# Understanding accessing the key and value in dictionaries Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

My code to address the problem below worked, but can someone help me understand this: why did my code only access the key and not the value? This has been a consistent issue I've had understanding dictionaries - just started studying them this week. I expected to either get an error or some jumbled mess of countries and numbers.

Can you perhaps explain how I would have written the code to add the key alone to a new list?

**Create a list of the countries that are in the dictionary golds, and assign that list to the variable name countries. Do not hard code this.**

```
golds = {"Italy": 12, "USA": 33, "Brazil": 15, "China": 27, "Spain": 19, "Canada": 22, "Argentina": 8, "England": 29}

countries = []
accum = 0
for item in golds:
    countries.append(item)
```

Comment: That's just the API of Python dictionaries – iterating the dictionary object is the same as iterating `my_dict.keys()`. This is consistent with the check `key in my_dict`, which tests whether `key` is present in `my_dict`.

Comment: This also means you can get the list of countries in your use case simply by `countries = list(golds)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop over the keys you do:

```
for k in golds.keys():
```

For the values:

```
for v in golds.values():
```

And for both:

```
for k, v in golds.items():
```

The Python creators had to choose one of the above to be the default experience when doing `for item in golds`. They decided upon the first one.

---

But why?

As the Sven and Amitai have pointed out, making it the default behavior to iterate over the keys is consistent with the ability to do `key in my_dict`. The more I think about it, `value in my_dict` would have just been a bad idea.

Also, I think Python wanted to be consistent with the way many other languages handled the situation at that time, so that brings up the question, which major language was the first one to loop over dictionaries? I tried to do some research to figure this out, but I couldn't find out which language was the first to make this choice :(

Comment: Iterating the dictionary gives the keys only, not the values.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks Sven. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com - possibly a matter of opinion, but choosing `keys` would be the obvious one, since it aligns with the `in` operator for membership testing.

Comment: In Rust, iterating over a `HashMap` (the equivalent of Python's `dict`) yields the items, not the keys.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating of a dictionary, you will be iterating over the **keys** only. Your piece of code:

```
for item in golds:
    countries.append(item)
```

does just that.

A much simpler way of doing this would be simply:

```
countries = list(golds)
```

because the `list` constructor iterates over a sequence, and in the case of a `dict`, that means its keys. While the above works, it is a bit obscure. A better options would be:

```
countries = list(golds.keys())
```

The `keys` method returns a sequence (iterator in Python 3, simply a list in Python 2) of all the dictionary keys. This is better (IMHO) than the previous method, because it clearly states the intent of the code, making it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the amazing world of dictionaries in Python :) Things can get a little confusing at first, but don't worry, it's okay.

Regarding to your question: when you iterate over a dictionary it returns only the key of the current item (that's why your code worked). If you want to access other data, there a couple of methods that will help:

1. `dict.values()` or `dict.keys()`:

Those methods will return a list of values or keys from the dict, something like this:

```py
golds = {"Italy": 12, "USA": 33, "Brazil": 15, "China": 27, "Spain": 19, "Canada": 22, "Argentina": 8, "England": 29}

countries = []
accum = 0

# Using .keys() (default behavior)
for item in golds.keys():
    countries.append(item)

# countries -> ["Italy", "USA", "Brazil", "China", "Spain", "Canada", "Argentina", "England"]

# Using .values()
for item in golds.values():
    countries.append(item)

# countries -> [12, 33, 15, 27, 19, 22, 8, 29]
```

2. `dict.items()`:

This method will return a list of tuples containing both the key and the value of the current item, being super useful in most cases. To use it, you have to use your `for` in a different way:

```py
# DISCLAIMER: key and value are just variable names, you can name them however you want
for key, value in golds.items():
    # key -> 'Italy'
    # value -> 12
    ...
```

Hope that helps!